# Optimization with no solution?!

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to find optimal solution of the following function:
$$\min[\log(x^2+2y^2-xy+1)+x^2+2y^2-xy]$$

The partial derivatives are:

$$df/x=(2x-y)/(x^2-xy+2y^2+1)+2x-y$$
and
$$df/y=(x-4y)/(x^2-xy+2y^2+1)-x+4y$$

The issue is that if I solve the above, I get one equation with no real solution, as pointed over here: [Method for solving the following equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742034/method-for-solving-the-following-equation)

How can one approach the above problem?

Comment: You provided a different equation in that linked thread, so the answers there don't pertain to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We are essentially minimizing $g(z)=\log(z+1)+z$ for $z \geq 0$, since $x^2 + 2y^2 - xy = (x-0.5y)^2 + \frac{7}{4}y^2 \geq 0$. The minimum of $g$ is attained for $z=0$. In your original variables, you have $(x-0.5y)^2 + \frac{7}{4}y^2 = 0$, which only true if $x=y=0$.

Comment: If the objective was to maximize, seems to me there is no maximum. Is there an easy way to prove that?

Comment: What $z$ guarantees an objective value of at least $K$? Can you find a matching $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Mick look at my answer to your previous question on this topic